# Using AJAX to post form data to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am simply trying to use the data submitted in a search form to query the database and bring back results similar to the search. My form looks like this:

```
 <div id="searchform">
    <form method="get">
    <form id="submitsearch">  
    <input id="shop" name="shop" type="text" placeholder="Find a shop" />
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Go"/>   
    </form>
    </form>
    <div id="searchresults">
    </div>
 </div>
```

the Javascript I've got is:

```
$("#submitsearch").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                $("#searchresults").html('');
                var values = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "external-data/search.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: values,
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#searchresults").html(data);
                    }
                    });
                });
    return false;
```

I have also tried...

```
   $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
            var form_data = $("#submitsearch").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            url: "external-data/search.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function (data) {
              $("#searchresults").html(data);
            }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

And this seems to work slightly as it shows results, the first doesn't do anything. It's not sending the data to the PHP page but the PHP I've got is:

```
<?php 
    $str_shops = '';
    $shop = $_POST['form_data'];
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name LIKE '%$shop%'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
        if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)); 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $str_shops .= "<strong>" . $row['name']  . "</strong><br>" .
    $row['address'] . "<br><br>"; 
 } 

mysqli_free_result($result); 
echo $str_shops; 
mysqli_close($db_server); 
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `print_r($_POST);` in your PHP code and a `console.log(data);` in your AJAX success function would show you exactly what **is** getting sent to PHP

Comment: Why is your form nested inside another form? Your first javascript snippet is correct (though i'm not sure what that `return false;` is there for)

Comment: You should be looking for data in `$_POST['shop']` not `$_POST['form_data']`

Comment: @KevinB nice spot - HTML spec doesn't allow nested forms, so this could be a reason you're having trouble too

Comment: Y two forms, I edited your html but you didn't accept.

Comment: @susheel - post it as an answer, don't go modifying code in peoples questions...

Comment: The edit button is for making minor changes that don't change what the question is asking, or what problem is being presented. Removing a nested form may radically change how the code operates (possibly making it work).

Comment: i thought its a typo and he is tying to ask something else in php :D fine :) :D >>>>>>

Comment: It very well may be, but only kathryn knows whether it's a typo in the question or in the code. If it is indeed a typo in the code, the question should be closed as such.

Comment: Sorted- thanks everyone! Stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two form tags.  This won't work.  You want one form tag with two attributes

```
<form method="get">
<form id="submitsearch">
```

to

```
<form method="get" id="submitsearch">
```

Comment: remove method="get" by default its get as you know...by the way he is posting data from ajax.

Comment: @susheel - I think having two form tags was the real problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without using html form.
first you call the php page and then display a data within html.
this is what I do?!

```
<div> 
 <input id="shop" type="text" placeholder="Find a shop" />
    <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Go"/>   
</div>
 <div id="searchresults">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
try
  {
    $.post("root/example.php",
      {
         'shop':$("#shop").val().trim()

     }, function(data){
           data=data.trim();
      $("#searchresults").html(data);
// this  data is data that the server sends back in case of ajax call you 
//can send any type of data whether json or json array or any other type 
//of data

         });
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }
  });


});
</script>
```